# How to save multiple images from database to TMemoryStream at runtime and extract them later on

Tags: arrays, delphi, blob, memorystream, delphi-xe3

I am creating a project at delphi(RAD Studio). There are images stored at database table at some rows. I want to extract images at runtime (for which I am using Array of TMemoryStream) and show them at frxReport.

My code snippet as follows

Public variable TStream is declared as

`Stream2 : Array of TStream; i,k: integer`

Code segment for view button click event, which is placed on MainForm and expected to show frxReport.

`

```
procedure TFrmMain.btnViewClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    i := 0;
    k := 0;
    UniTable1.SQL.Text := 'Select * from userplays order by id';
    UniTable1.Execute;

    rowcount := UniTable1.RecordCount;

    SetLength(myid, rowcount);
    SetLength(mydesc, rowcount);
    SetLength(myimg, rowcount);
    SetLength(Stream2, rowcount);

      while not UniTable1.Eof do
      begin
        try
          Stream2[k] := TMemoryStream.Create;
          myid[k] := UniTable1.FieldByName('id').Value;
          Stream2[k] := UniTable1.CreateBlobStream(TBlobField(UniTable1.FieldByName('image')), bmRead);
          mydesc[k] := UniTable1.FieldByName('description').Value;

         UniTable1.Next;
         inc(k);

        finally
           //Stream2[k].Free;
        end;

      end;

      frxUserDataSet1.RangeEnd := reCount;
      frxUserDataSet1.RangeEndCount := rowcount;
      frxReport1.ShowReport;
      i := 0;
end;
```

`

However this method is not loading any image to Stream2 array. There is an option to use array of JPEGImage however if JPEGImage array used then it would be problem to display it on frxRaport at

`procedure TFrmMain.frxReport1GetValue(const VarName: string; var Value: Variant);`

`

```
Graphic := TJPEGImage.Create;
Graphic.LoadFromStream(Stream2[j]);
TfrxPictureView(frxreport1.FindObject('Picture1')).Picture.Graphic := Graphic;
```

`
   Kindly let me know how to do this.

Comment: what exactly is Delphi version you use???  My suggestion: use some file container: .TAR or .ZIP or whatever - put files into it, and then put the file into the database BLOB. For example in Delphi XE2 you can create in-memory ZIP over TStream without even touching the disk. So you can directly use TMemoryStream or TBLobStream to contain many files inside

Comment: I am using Delphi version  XE-3

Comment: then that is a way to go for you, make in-memory zip over stream and put it into DB.   a very distant code but mentioning few classes methods for you to use https://github.com/the-Arioch/avemey.com/blob/master/zexmlss/src/zeZippyXE2.pas

Comment: I am not sure if i understand Your problem. Are You storing many images in single db field ? If not, why just not connect masterdata band in FR with Your Unitable1 through frxDBDataset and eventually load it directly from DB with OnGetValue if You need to manipulate it? I understand that You try to decouple FR from Database but isn't it a bit overkill ?

Comment: I am using frxUserDataset with SQLite table else I would have connected it.

Comment: OK, then OnNext frxUserDataset event: Unitable1.Next; and load it as usual with OnGetValue, or add frxDBDataset connected to Unitable1 or...

Comment: You use of global variables makes my feel sick

Comment: Your second `Stream2[k]` assignment is wrong. You should use `Stream2[k].LoadFromStream(the blob stream);` to load it.

Comment: @TomBrunberg and don't forget to free the blob stream after loading it.

Comment: it seems like there is no method like LoadFromStream at Stream...

Comment: define `Stream2 : Array of TMemoryStream; ` http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/System.Classes.TMemoryStream.LoadFromStream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However this method is not loading any image to Stream2 array

In your current code you are first assigning a newly created `TMemoryStream` to `Stream2[k]`:

```
      Stream2[k] := TMemoryStream.Create;
```

then you are throwing the `TMemoryStream` away (creating a memory leak) and replacing it with the blob stream you create:

```
      Stream2[k] := UniTable1.CreateBlobStream(TBlobField(UniTable1.FieldByName('image')), bmRead);
```

But you never read from the blob stream.

Here's the `while` loop rewritten (untested)

```
var
  blobstream: TStream;
  Stream2: array of TMemoryStream;

  ....
  // read 'id', 'description' and 'image' fields to respective arrays
  while not UniTable1.Eof do
  begin
    myid[k] := UniTable1.FieldByName('id').Value;
    mydesc[k] := UniTable1.FieldByName('description').Value;

    blobstream := UniTable1.CreateBlobStream(TBlobField(UniTable1.FieldByName('image')), bmRead);
    try
      Stream2[k] := TMemoryStream.Create;
      Stream2[k].LoadFromStream(blobstream);
    finally
      blobstream.Free;
    end;

    UniTable1.Next;
    inc(k);
  end;
```

Btw, I would recommend to define a record to hold the `id`, `description` and `image` together, and then an array of those records, instead of three separate arrays. Much simpler to manage only one array instead of three.

Comment: hi, it is working but showing same image(particularly last one in the memorystream array) at frxReport. 
Graphic.LoadFromStream(Stream2[j]); It seems like it is saving same image (last one) in the entire array.

Comment: @NinadAvasare I don't see how that would be possible, unless you have only one image saved in the data base. If you step through the code in the debugger, do you see e.g. the `id` value change for each round? Or the size of the `Stream2[k]` after `LoadFromStream()`?

Comment: Hi Tom, Yes id value changing at each round in the loop. Also ID and DESC both are updating successfully and displaying output at fastreport, Problem is only with image field as I am using Stream to save and load them.

Comment: Stream is working but it is saving image for last row in the table only. If last row in the table has image then at FR it is displaying only last row image at last id and other id's image as blank. If image field in the last row of the table dont have any image then at  FR all id's image is being shown as blank..Yes, but size of Stream2 is not changing it is being same all time throughout the loop.

Comment: Please, whe you refer to variables or objects, use their names. When you talk about table, do you mean `UniTable1`? If your problem now is showing the images in FastReport, that would be another question. I answered your question given in the header of your post: "*How to save multiple images from database to TMemorystreams*". Please pay attention, I asked about the size of each `Stream2[k]` stream, not the `Stream2` array. I mean, is each `TMemoryStream` same or different size after being loaded with image from the blob stream? Are you sure you have different images in the db?

Comment: Hi Tom, it is working perfectly now..Amazing answer and superb help...many thanks...

Answer (score 2):

I think in your situation most obvious thing would be just connect existing DataSet ( Unitable1) directly into DataBand in frxReport. I don't see why you would need to use frxUserDataset instead of frxDBDataset with its DataSet property set to Unitable1 since you created it anyway.

If you really need a list of objects then I would take a different approach.
Your multiple global variables look ugly and are dangerous (i,k...)

I would create a class that holds your data and populate this data into a 
TObjectList from System.Generics.Collection:

```
unit DataPack;

interface
uses ExtCtrls...System.SysUtils;

type

 TMyDataPack = class(TObject)

   private
   Query: TFDQuery; //O r TUniQery
   _MyId: Integer;
   _MyDescription: String;
   _MyImage: TImage;
   _Loaded: Boolean;
   function LoadData: boolean;
  protected
  public
   constructor Create(Data: TFDQuery); //Or Uniquery
   property MyId: Integer read _MyId;
   property MyDescription: String read _MyDescription;
   property MyImage: TImage read _MyImage;
   property Loaded: Boolean read _Loaded;
 end;

implementation

{ TMyDataPack }

constructor TMyDataPack.Create(Data: TFDQuery);
 begin
  Inherited Create;
  Query:=Data;
  _Loaded:=true;
  if not (LoadData) then
  _Loaded:=false;

 end;

 function TMyDataPack.LoadData: boolean;
 var
 Stream: TStream;
 begin
 Stream:= TStream.Create;
    Stream:=Query.CreateBlobStream(TBlobField(Query.FieldByName('image')), bmRead);

 try
   _MyImage:=TImage.Create(nil);
   _MyImage.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(Stream);
   _MyDescription:=Query.FieldByName('description').AsString;
   _MyId:=Query.FieldByName('CategoryId').AsInteger;
 except on E: Exception do
  begin
  FreeAndNil(Stream);
  FreeAndNil(_MyImage);  
  Exit(false);
  end;

 end;
 FreeAndNil(Stream);
 Result:=true;
 end;

 end.
```

Then in your main code:

```
procedure TMain.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
DataRow: TMyDataPack;
List: TObjectList<TMyDataPack>;
Num: integer;
CurrentImage: TImage;
CurrentDescription: String;
CurrentId: integer;
begin
  UniTable1.SQL.Text:='SELECT  * FROM Userplays';
  UniTable1.Open();

List:=TObjectList<TMyDataPack>.Create;
while not (UniTable1.Eof) do
  begin
   DataRow:=TMyDataPack.Create(UniTable1);
   if(DataRow.Loaded) then
   List.Add(DataRow);
   UniTable1.Next;
  End;


for Num:=0 to List.Count do
  begin
    CurrentDescription:=List[Num].MyDescription;
    CurrentImage:=List[Num].MyImage;
    CurrentId:=List[Num].MyId;
    //List[Num].MyImage.Picture.SaveToFile('Some'+IntToStr(Num)+'.bmp');
   // You might save it to file then...  
    end;
   end;

  end.
```

Then pass an ObjectList further, just remember to free it at the end.

You might further expand it by creating class factory to create different objects if you'd need for example use different database with same data, 
perform check if image is actually Bmp or Jpg and so on.
You might even just pass a query without setting it's SQL and get TobjectList as property.